# PHP - open a csv file, make a change and save

Tags: php, csv

I'm having problems with a script which should open a csv stored in the same directory, make a change, and then save as a new file.

```
$path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/orderfeed/";
$rawexport = 'rawexport.csv';
$tempfile = 'temporary.csv';
$exportfiltered = 'export-filtered.csv';


if (file_exists($rawexport)) {

    if ( unlink($exportfiltered) ) { // Delete previous filtered export
        print "Deleted previous $exportfiltered before import<br>";     
    } else {
        print "Delete of previous $exportfiltered before import failed!<br>";
    }

    $input = fopen($rawexport, 'r'); //open for reading
    $output = fopen($tempfile, 'w'); //open for writing

    while( false !== ( $data = fgetcsv($input) ) ){ //read each line as an array

        //modify data here      
        if ( $data[14] == 'Rate Name' ) {
            $data[14] = 'RATE_NAME';
        }

        //write modified data to temporary file
        fputcsv( $output, $data);

    }

    //close both files
    fclose( $input );
    fclose( $output );

    if ( unlink($rawexport) ) { // Delete raw export file
        print "Deleted $rawexport<br>";     
    } else {
        print "Delete of $rawexport failed!<br>";
    }

    if ( copy($path.$tempfile, $path.$exportfiltered) ) { // Rename temporary to new
        print "Export renamed<br>";
    } else {
        print "Export was not renamed!<br>";
    }

    echo '<pre>';print_r(error_get_last());echo '</pre>';



} else {
    die('Import file not found!');  
}
```

It works perfectly on the first run, but on subsequent runs although the temporary file created shows any updates in the source csv, they arent being saved to the 'export-filtered.csv' file?

I was using rename() rather than copy() originally but that didn't work either.

Comment: you first trying delete rewexport and after trying to save

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: There are a few mistakes (at last for me) about your code. Sometimes you're using `$path` and others don't. If `$path` is needed at any point, it always needed. As: `fopen($path.$rawexport, 'r');` or `file_exists($path.$rawexport)`. By the way, I didn't get what is happening with your code.

Comment: Thanks @GabrielHeming I see what you’re saying about consistency, originally I wan't using paths at all everything was within one directory, but started adding paths in desperation! When you say 'By the way, I didn't get what is happening with your code' do you mean it worked as it should?

Comment: @Sleep.Create.Repeat. Yes, I do. I can't test your code, but it seems to work as expected. The only inconsistency is the `$path` variable, as I said before. Maybe it's more an OS problem than a problem with your code. Have you tried to run on another system?

Comment: Thanks again @GabrielHeming - I'll try it in another environment

Comment: Let me know whether it worked or not.

Comment: @GabrielHeming sorry for the delay - I revised the code slightly and went with your advise over the paths, and got it working, so thank you.